# masking with svg mask defined in html

Tags: html, css, svg, mask

I am trying some very simple test of masking with an SVG shape I create in the html content.
I have tried different option:

- mask, -webkit-mask
- mask-image, -webkit-mask-image
- different MaskUnits and MaskContentUnits
- mask-type: luminance or not

I cannot make it work, I must do something wrong and stupid.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Mask with SVG</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <style>
        .testMask {
            -webkit-mask-image: url(#torch);
            mask-image:url(#torch);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
            <mask id="torch">
                <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.1" fill="white" />
            </mask>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    <div id="mainPage">
        <img src="/img/Japan.jpg" class="testMask">
    </div>
</body>
```

Is there something wrong in there?
Second question would be, is there a way to change the mask coordinates by js?  I want it to follow the mouse pointer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The default units for `<mask>` content elements are `objectBoundingBox` (ie. `maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"`).  In this mode, the coordinates used in the elements that are part of the mask are *relative to the bounding box*.  In other words, (0,0) is top left, and (1,1) is bottom right.

So your circle at (50,50) is way off the edge of the mask.

It's preferable to stick with objectBoundingBox units, so try the following instead:

```
<mask id="torch" >
    <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.1" fill="white" />
</mask>
```

**Note:**

Masking with an inline SVG works in Firefox (see http://jsfiddle.net/dv6mx96t/), but not Chrome.  For masks that work cross-browser, you need to use an external image.  That image can be an SVG, or a PNG etc.

For example:

```
.testMask {
    mask: url(mask.svg);
}
```

Where *mask.svg* is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
    <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".35" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to say I played with those, it does not work either.  And I forgot to say, it's not that I don't have a mask:  the img is not showing at all.  If I remove its class it does, so definitely there is problem there.

Comment: Actually it's not showing in Chrome and Safari, but showing unmasked under firefox.  Why did they kill Flash again? :)

Comment: Sorry. My bad.  Inline SVG masks work in Firefox, but not in Chrome.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I tried with a .png, I got no luck either.  I will try with a .svg tomorrow... should I just save the text in an external file?  How can I include it in the html?  While I be able to manipulate the mask from the DOM?  The question of compatibility with chrome is strange, it didn't work either with Firefox:  the img showed but not masked.

Comment: See my answer update. I link to an example that works on FF.  Plus there is an example of how to use an external SVG.  If you use an external file, you won't be able to manipulate the mask via the DOM.  You might find it easier to just put your image-to-be-masked in the SVG. Then it should work on all browsers.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it will not be useable for my need:  I want the mask to follow the mouse move.  I am very, very surprised and frustrated that so many years later, html5 and css3 are so tedious and not at the level of something I would do in Flash, I did in Flash, in 10 minutes.  I really wonder why they wanted to kill flash while not providing any suitable alternative.  It seems those standards are not mature, and not adopted by browsers.  What a shame :(

Comment: What I don't understand as well, I found that link which tends to pretend every browser supports that:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5

Comment: Inline SVG works fine in all modern browsers. I think you are confused. And I don't believe you can use Flash operations on HTML either, so your complaint seems invalid.  It is quite easy to make a mask follow the mouse in SVG.

Comment: Like I said before. If you want something that works cross-browser, don't try to apply SVG effects to HTML. Move your image into the SVG and do it all there. http://jsfiddle.net/dv6mx96t/3/

Comment: hum, I am confused, you wrote that inline SVG work in Firefox but not in Chrome.  So if I understand, it works with all browsers if the image is embedded in SVG but only with Firefox if the img is defined in html?  Actually what is confusing for me is 1) browser support 2) the boundaries between html, css, javascript and svg.  HTML and CSS were clear for me before, and I used to manage everthing with javascript.  Now with webkit / webkit animate, canvas, @keyframes, it will take time for me to learn where to do what for which result.

Comment: With Flash I add one technology only, here I have the feeling I need to learn several languages (different markups, script and css) to achieve the result I used to have in a more uniform manner.  And Flash had a great IDE, suitable for artist or developers.  It is strange that Adobe haven't done yet the exact same IDE for alternative techs.  I downloaded Google Web Designer, I will try.  Anyway thanks a lot, I will try your latest method shortly.

Comment: Perhaps [Adobe Edge Animate](https://creative.adobe.com/products/animate) is what you are wanting.

Comment: I had a quick glance, and even if it seems promising, it seems far from what Flash used to be, but that's just a first impression.

Comment: I am trying your method, I get an image masked, but I am struggling with the width and height as I want the image to be displayed at its actual size without me entering the size in pixels.  If I don't input size at all, nothing shows :(